# Creating shared folder between Win 2008 R2 and Win 2012 Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server and need to share a folder on this server to be visible on an Amazon AWS Windows 2012 server. The 2012 server acts as a failover server.

The purpose of this is to copy files nightly to the Windows 2012 server.

I am new to setting up servers so what is the easiest way to get this done?

Comment: So you have an on premises server that serves files to your local users and you need to sync these files to your AWS EC2 instance so that the EC2 instance can act as a failover server for the on premises server?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: How do you plan on getting users connected to the failover server and it's shares if need be?

Comment: So, I'm setting this up for a web app. For this app to work, I just need to get the information from one server onto the other..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you have two possibilities:

1. publish one of the server using a public IP address and open/redirect the required port (135-139 and 445 TCP/UDP) - this is **highly insecure**
2. establish a VPN tunnel between the servers and directly connect to the private IP address - this is the **recommended solution**

You had multiple options to establish the VPN tunnel: you can use the AWS VPN service, Windows's integrated VPN technology, OpenVPN, ecc. Simply pick the one that is better suited to your network topology and budget.

Anyway, if you only want a off-site backup, maybe you will be better served with by a simpler solution such as remote FTP server.

Comment: So, if I install a winScp server on the AWS Windows Server 2012 would that work and be secure?

Comment: It is a possibility, such as FTP/S, SMB, ecc.

Comment: I see.. so I can remote desktop into both servers using the same VPN. Does that mean they are on the same tunnel to share a folder through?

Comment: I can't know that ;) They are your servers on your network, so *you* should be able to tell us

Comment: Haha alright, they are on the same VPN tunnel.. I set up a shared folder on the 2008 on premises box. How would I set up this folder to be seen by the 2012 amazon box?

Comment: If they are on the same tunnel, it should suffice to direct the Win2012 amazon server to \\<ip>\<sharename> where <ip> is the IP address of your Win2008 server and <sharename> is, err, the share name.

Comment: Still doesn't work.. are there any other steps I could take to specifically point the AWS server to the Win2008 server?